# MediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer times out when seeking with Ogg audio files

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

When playing .ogg files .dequeueOutputBuffer() always times out with MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER after a call to MediaExtractor.seekTo(). This causes problems because I am trying to create near seamless seeking. The maximum blocking time is irrelevant, it always times out no matter how long it is set.

This happens with all .ogg files and no other audio file types.

Here is the relevant code, the timeout happens at

```
final int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_US);
```

It happens after every call to seekTo() with .ogg files, is there anyway to correct this?

```
public MediaCodecMp3Decoder(String fullPath) throws IOException
    {
        extractor = new MediaExtractor();
        extractor.setDataSource(fullPath);

        format = extractor.getTrackFormat(0);
        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        durationUs = format.getLong(MediaFormat.KEY_DURATION);

        codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
        codec.configure(format, null, null, 0);
        codec.start();
        codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
        codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

        extractor.selectTrack(0);
        info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    }


public byte[] decodeChunk()
    {
        advanceInput();

        final int res = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, TIMEOUT_US);
        if (res >= 0)
        {
            int outputBufIndex = res;
            ByteBuffer buf = codecOutputBuffers[outputBufIndex];
            if(chunk == null || chunk.length != info.size)
            {
                chunk = new byte[info.size];
            }
            buf.get(chunk);
            buf.clear();
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false);
        }
        if ((info.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0)
        {
            sawOutputEOS = true;
        }
        else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED)
        {
            codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
        }
        else if (res == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED)
        {
            format = codec.getOutputFormat();
            Log.d("MP3", "Output format has changed to " + format);
        }

        return chunk;
    }

private void advanceInput()
{
    boolean sawInputEOS = false;

    int inputBufIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_US);
    if (inputBufIndex >= 0)
    {
        ByteBuffer dstBuf = codecInputBuffers[inputBufIndex];

        int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, 0);
        long presentationTimeUs = 0;

        if (sampleSize < 0)
        {
            sawInputEOS = true;
            sampleSize = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();
            currentTimeUs += presentationTimeUs - lastPresentationTime;
            lastPresentationTime = presentationTimeUs;
        }

        codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex,
                0,
                sampleSize,
                presentationTimeUs,
                sawInputEOS ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM : 0);
        if (!sawInputEOS)
        {
            extractor.advance();
        }
    }
}

public void seek(long timeInUs)
    {
        extractor.seekTo(timeInUs, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
        lastPresentationTime = currentTimeUs = timeInUs;
        codec.flush();
    }
```

Here is the only logcat prior and after a seekTo(), the buffer underrun on the AudioTrack is due to the 1 second timeout I currently have set for dequeueOutputBuffer()

```
03-01 13:48:25.042: I/AudioFlinger(125): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4099) from active list on thread 0x40b42008
03-01 13:48:25.312: W/AudioTrack(29349): releaseBuffer() track 0x6a110c10 name=s:125;n:3;f:-1 disabled due to previous underrun, restarting
```

Also I should note that the calls to seekTo() and decodeChunk() are happening on different threads, but they are synchronized on the same Object.

```
synchronized (decodeLock)
{
    decoder.seek(timeInUs);
}

synchronized (decodeLock)
{
    input = decoder.decodeChunk();
...
}
```

Comment: could you please share logcat? what size readSampleData returns after you make seek?

Comment: I posted LogCat, nothing unusual. sampleSize is 147 after a seek, a normal size that matches sizes during normal operation. The same with presentationTimeUs.

Comment: On which version of Android are you seeing this? There were some problems related to this that were fixed in KLP I believe.

Comment: It's 4.4.2, Key Lime Pie, it's not out yet?

Comment: The changes I'm thinking of are in 4.4.2, and what you're doing is similar to what some of the CTS tests are doing. It might be interesting to compile and run the "DecoderTest" CTS test and see if that works for you. Also, when you run your code, does it actually end up queueing buffers *into* the MediaCodec after the seek?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `seek` calls `codec.flush` which will discard any decoded buffers in the output queue. If `decoder.seek` is just before `decoder.decodeChunk` then output queue will be empty. Ensure you have dequeued output before calling `seek`.

Also, some decoders (chipset/OEM-dependent) will have an input threshold. Try calling `advanceInput` multiple times before expecting any output buffers.

For example, see ExoPlayer's input/output work loop in
[MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java#L502).